# Integration of Bessel function of first kind multiplied with Gaussian

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, gaussian

I like to know how to proceed with the following two integrations

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}J^{2}_{n\pm1}(x)e^{-(a+nb)^{2}}\,dn$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}J_{n+1}(x)J_{n-1}(x)e^{-(a+nb)^{2}}\,dn$$

Note that $x$ is independent of $n$.

Comment: What are the arguments of the Bessel functions ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the arguments. Now it is corrected. They are independent of $n$.

Comment: Where did you find these expressions? (!) And, is there reason to believe that a 'nice' closed form exists?

Comment: These kinds of expressions arise in the kinetic theory of plasma. Also, I do not want a closed form for the integrations an approximate form would also suffice.

Comment: For first integral:$$\frac{1-e^{-\frac{\pi ^2}{4 b^2}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  a}{b}+2 x\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } x | b| }$$ if $x\to \infty$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you @MariuszIwaniuk for the answer. Would it be possible for you to direct me to some sort derivation of the above result?